# Not displayed value into textarea from controller

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

After typing in the "YourText" text zone and pressing the "Encode" button, the encoded text does not appear in the "EncodedText" text zone. If you replace the @html.textarea with "DisplayFor", the encoded text is displayed.

I need to display encoded text in a text area.
And if that works out, then read the EncodedText textzone and, by pressing the "Decode" button, decode the text into the "Decoded text" text zone.

[This project on GitHub](https://github.com/EugeneChepurko/StringCoder_ASP.NET_MVC/tree/master/StringCoder_ASP.NET_MVC)

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EncodeText(FormData formData)
    {
        SelectList items = new SelectList(ciphers);
        ViewBag.Ciphers = items;
        // Caesar cipher decode CODE here...

        return View(formData);
    }
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EncodeText(FormData formData, FormCollection form)
    {
        SelectList items = new SelectList(ciphers);
        ViewBag.Ciphers = items;
        // Caesar cipher encode CODE here...
        return View(formData);
    }
```

**View "Index":**

```html
@model StringCoder_ASP.NET_MVC.Models.FormData
<div>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EncodeText", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.Label("Input your text:") <br />
            @Html.TextArea("YourText") <br />
            @Html.Label("Your encoded text:") <br />
            @Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.EncodedText, ViewBag.EncText as string) <br />
            @Html.Label("Your decoded text:") <br />
            @Html.TextAreaFor(d => d.DecodedText) <br />
            <div id="buttonEncode">
                <input id="button" type="submit" value="Encode" formaction="@Url.Action("EncodeText", "Home")" /> <br />
            </div>
            <div id="buttonDecode">
                <input id="button" type="submit" value="Decode" formaction="@Url.Action("DecodeText", "Home")" /> <br />
            </div>
            <div>@Html.Label("Select a cipher:", null, new { @id = "labelCipher" })</div>
            <div>@Html.DropDownList("Ciphers", ViewBag.Ciphers as SelectList, null, new { @id = "dropdownlistCipher" })</div>
            <div>@Html.Label("Enter a key:", null, new { @id = "labelKey" })</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBox("tbkey", null, new { @id = "tbkey" })</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**View "EncodeText:"**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("EncodeText", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            @Html.Label("Input your text:") <br />
            @Html.TextArea("YourText") <br />
            @Html.Label("Your encoded text:") <br />
            @Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.EncodedText@*(string)ViewBag.EncText*@) <br />
            @Html.Label("Your decoded text:") <br />
            @Html.TextAreaFor(d => d.DecodedText) <br />
            <div id="buttonEncode">
                <input id="button" type="submit" value="Encode" formaction="@Url.Action("EncodeText", "Home")" /> <br />
            </div>
            <div id="buttonDecode">
                <input id="button" type="submit" value="Decode" formaction="@Url.Action("DecodeText", "Home")" /> <br />
            </div>
            <div>@Html.Label("Select a cipher:", null, new { @id = "labelCipher" })</div>
            <div>@Html.DropDownList("Ciphers", ViewBag.Ciphers as SelectList, null, new { @id = "dropdownlistCipher" })</div>
            <div>@Html.Label("Enter a key:", null, new { @id = "labelKey" })</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBox("tbkey", null, new { @id = "tbkey" })</div>
        }
```

View "Decode" are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a property Model.EncodedText and a ViewBag variable ViewBag.EncText? Ideally, you should put the encoded text inside the model property.

You can try displaying the text without an HtmlHelper:

```
<textarea id="EncodedText" name="EncodedText">@Model.EncodedText</textarea> @*or ViewBag.EncText*@
```

Comment: it's work! thx you! But why this not worked with @html.textarea("EncodedText", Model.EncodedText)

Comment: I don't know why but the html tag helper is having trouble to display your encoded text.